# Как правильно настроить боевой сервер на nginx?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

Разворачиваю свой webpy проект на сервере digital ocean

Делаю все по туториалу [https://gist.github.com/TimSC/04993f1e3668d1decdfb](http://%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83)

но столкнулся со следующей проблемой после создания файла **/etc/init/mon.conf**

со следующим содержимым

```
description "mon uwsgi"
author "TSC"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

env DIR=/run/uwsgi/app/mon
env USER=www-data
env GROUP=www-data
env PERMS=0755

pre-start script
  mkdir -p $DIR              || true
  chmod $PERMS $DIR       || true
  chown $USER:$GROUP $DIR || true
end script

exec uwsgi /var/srv/www/mon/app/mon.xml --logto /var/srv/www/mon/logs/uwsgi.log
```

и запуска команды `sudo service mon start` я получаю ошибку...

> Failed to start mon.service: Unit mon.service not found.

Что в свою очередь приводит к ошибке запуска nginx поскольку файл mon.socket не был создан и nginx не может его найти.

Как решить проблему? система ubuntu 16.04

Comment: А как выглядит файл mon.service ?И есть ли он? По дефолту должен быть в `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`
И есть ли что-то похожее на mon в выводе `systemctl list-units`?

Comment: да, нашел что у меня systemd, а не upstart... папки system у меня нет. в выводе ни чего похожего на mon я не увидел ибо и не создавал собственно..

Comment: я тоже столкнулся с подобной ошибкой. в общем так, никсы постепенно переходят на использование вуместо upstart на systemd. в связи с чем пропадает возможность использовать такое системное слово как service, если используешь его для запуска\остановки демонов. т.е. теперь ты не сможешь создавать .ини и надеятся, что они поймаются сами... у меня нет готового пока ответа на твой вопрос, но могу порекомендовать вот что:
- либо поднимай старую но поддерживаемую версию никса, к примеру убунту 14.04
- либо попробуй поискать как настроисть демон для systemd
- либо попробуй обьеденить эту https://www.8h